# Angular environment files do not get swapped in time

Tags: angular, environment-variables, ng-modules, angular-compiler, angulartics2

I am using Angular 9, View Engine compiler.

I have 2 files where I store environment values:

**environment.ts**:

```
export const environment: any = {
    production: false,
};
```

**environment.prod.ts**:

```
export const environment: any = {
    production: true
}
```

Here is a part of my **angular.json** configuration that swaps environment.ts with environment.prod.ts when building the app for production environment:

```
"configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "app/src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I am using environment variables to configure the third-party service if it should or should not run on developer mode. However, in production (when building with --prod flag), it was not working properly. After some investigation we have found out that the third party service is getting the value from **environment.ts** and not from the **environment.prod.ts**.

Here is the trimmed down version of **app.module.ts** where the configuration is made:

```
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // Google Analytics (via Angulartics2)
    Angulartics2Module.forRoot({
      developerMode: !environment.production // <-- Gets incorrect value: 'true' on production mode
    }),                                      // but should be 'false'
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    console.log(!environment.production); // <-- Logs correct value: 'false' on production mode
  }
}
```

Later testing at runtime that Angulartics2 third-party service indeed received the wrong value:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class GoogleAnalyticsService {
  constructor(
    private angulartics2: Angulartics2
  ) {
    console.log(this.angulartics2.settings.developerMode); // Logs 'true'
  }
}
```

Why is the wrong environment value being received in `AppModule`'s `@NgModule` decorator function, but then - the correct one in `AppModule`'s `constructor` and the service that executes later at runtime? Does the `@NgModule()` decorator function for `AppModule` gets executed before the environment files get swapped by the compiler?

Comment: Please post your tsconfig.json. Because '@env/environment' has unclear origin.

Comment: I have updated the code with the relative path instead

Comment: It should be `import { environment } from './../environments/environment'`. Does the issue persist?

Comment: Yes, the .prod part gets removed by the compiler, I have updated the code again, sorry about that. In any case, I can assure you that the issue is not with imports

Comment: Well when something is miss-imported, then the problem is with import. But probably not directly in your case. Your code seems correct, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Angular [uses Webpack](https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/885) for file replacements specified in **Angular.json**. So the file replacement happens at some point in the build phase, which is probably after the code in decorators such as `@NgModule` gets resolved by the Angular compiler. Thus, it seems one should not use environment variables when configuring `@NgModule` imports.